# Do XAML controls have a center, which can be manipulated?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout

I have a XAML file, based on `Grid`s, `StackPanel`s, ...: on one row, I have a control, located on a `StackPanel`. Next to that there's another `StackPanel`. Next to that, there's a `Grid`, containing another `StackPanel` with two `UserControl`s (`UC1_1`, `UC1_2`, `UC2_1`, `UC2_2`, ...), and so on, and so on, ...

Under that, I have another `UserControl` (`OtherUC`), and now I would like to do align that control on the other ones. In order to do that, I would need something like:

```
OtherUC.Margin.X = StackPanel1.Width + StackPanel1.Margin.X + 
                   StackPanel2.Width + StackPanel2.Margin.X + 
                   UC1_1.Width + UC1_1.Margin.X + 
                   UC1_2.Width + UC1_2.Margin.X + ...
```

It's possible that I don't need to add margins and widths, but that's not the point: the point is just that I need to add a lot of stuff for something, which could be so much easier as follows:

```
OtherUC.Center.X = UC1_4.Center.X;
```

Is that possible? Is there a `Center` property to a XAML control which can be set that easily?

Comment: I don't follow your explanation of what you're trying to achieve. The answer is no.

Comment: `Margin.X` does not exist. WPF has these layout mechanisms. And you should get acustomed to them https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/alignment-margins-and-padding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There's no `Center` property that You can use.

But I guess, if You'd like to center Controls based on other Controls positions, You can play with `RenderTransfrom`, either in XAML with binding, or in the Code Behind.

For explanations sake, here's example in CodeBehind.

Here's the minimal UI to reproduce the problem

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle x:Name="rect1"
               Width="10"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Fill="Red"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rect2"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Width="10"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Fill="Blue"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rect3"
               Grid.Row="2"
               Width="10"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Fill="Green"/>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle x:Name="stackRect1"
                   Width="50"
                   Margin="10"
                   Fill="Pink"/>

        <Rectangle x:Name="stackRect2"
                   Width="250"
                   Margin="10"
                   Fill="Pink"/>

        <Rectangle x:Name="stackRect3"
                   Width="278"
                   Margin="10"
                   Fill="Pink"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and here's code behind

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}

private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var a = stackRect1.TranslatePoint(new Point(stackRect1.Width / 2, 0), this);
    var b = stackRect2.TranslatePoint(new Point(stackRect2.Width / 2, 0), this);
    var c = stackRect3.TranslatePoint(new Point(stackRect3.Width / 2, 0), this);

    rect1.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(a.X, 0);
    rect2.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(b.X, 0);
    rect3.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(c.X, 0);
}
```

As You can see I use `TranslatePoint` to get centers of each 'Control', and then `RenderTranform` selected 'Control' to that center.

Comment: Do not use RenderTransform as a replacement for proper layout. If you need absolute positioning, use a Canvas.

Comment: @Clemens: can I use a `Canvas` without needing to rewrite the entire XAML? (I'm working on an application I inherited from a colleague who left the firm, and I'm reluctant to do big modifications.)

Comment: I've posted the answer based on my best understanding of the problem, but I agree this maybe can be solved with proper layout. Hard to tell without actual code for the layout.